# Custom attribute names for JSON marshalling

Tags: json, spring, jaxb, spring-boot

I implemented a little application that delivers some JSON data as part of a REST API. For legacy reason a client has very special requirements for the attribute names: using underscores and written in UPPERCASE.

So I have this class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Values {

    public Values(String firstValue, String secondValue) {
        this.firstValue = firstValue;
        this.secondValue = secondValue;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name = "FIRST_VALUE")
    private String firstValue;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "SECOND_VALUE")
    private String secondValue;

    public String getFirstValue() {
        return firstValue;
    }

    public String getSecondValue() {
        return secondValue;
    }
}
```

To deliver as JSON I have a small controller:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/values")
    @ResponseBody
    public Values getValues() {
       return new Value("v1", "v2");
    }
}
```

I expect the following delivered by the controller

```
{
    "FIRST_VALUE": "v1",
    "SECOND_VALUE": "v2"
}
```

But instead it ignores the @XmlAttribute annotations and delivers

```
{
    "firstValue": "v1",
    "secondValue": "v2"
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the type of the response is JSON, you should use `@JsonProperty()`.

So add `@JsonProperty(value = "FIRST_VALUE")` and `@JsonProperty(value = "SECOND_VALUE")` to your `firstValue` and `secondValue` fields.